# Confused about web fonts

Tags: fonts

I am confused about fonts for use in websites.

I have a font that was purchased - it says it is a desktop font. I'm calling it into the css using @fontface and its working fine. The site is currently only on my localhost.

I am aware of fonts like Google fonts and have used them before but don't need to for this project.

Can I use the desktop font for the website and just load the font folder onto my server? I realize that desktop fonts are meant for use with applications like photoshop - but is there any reason I cant use it for my website using @fontface?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to the legal implications of licensing

Comment: @RowlandShaw I disagree. It seems to be asking whether there's a (technological) difference between fonts which are used for the web and those which are used for non-web apps.

Comment: OP, if the question is about licensing/legal issues, the short answer is that it's off-topic for this site and you'll have to look at the license for the font you purchased (or contact the company, or maybe a lawyer). If it's just about file formats and how to use a font (assuming you have license to do so) on your website, please clarify that in your question.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard well, that's a reason why you can't just use any old font...

Comment: I see  - ok let me clarify. I was vaguely aware that licensing is an issue but my question mostly relates to the technical aspects of it. I was asking if, apart from licensing issues, are there technical reasons why a desktop font cant be used as a web font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically any valid font file should work with `@fontface`.  The file (.otf, .ttf, .woff, etc...) is handled by the browser as a font file - the only significant difference between a desktop font and a web font is, in some cases, a web font will have extra optimizations made to it since it is being delivered over the web.  This does not prevent a desktop font from being used, it just makes a font specifically designed for the web more efficient.

A good  description of these differences can be found here: http://creativepro.com/print-vs-web-fonts-what-s-the-difference/

Regardless of the file working or not you need to review the font's licensing to know for sure if it is allowed or not.  Some purchased fonts have licenses that allow for use over the web while others may not.  Since you purchased the font file your best bet is to either read the license that came with the font file or contact the publisher and verify how it can and cannot be used.

Fonts are no different than any other asset (graphics, audio, video, etc...) and they should be treated the same way in regards to licensing.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I think that answers my question

Comment: @murph  Good.  If you feel it's a complete answer take a second and click the accept answer checkmark.  It's a good way for both you and I to gain reputation on the site.